# How to get last nonnull value in usql windowing expression?

Tags: u-sql

I'm trying to gel last nonnull value in windowing expression:

```
LAST_VALUE([b]) OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS bf
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
I wrote my custom aggregate function and it doesn't work too.

```
public class LastNonNull<T> : IAggregate<T, T>
        where T : class
    {
        T last;

        public override void Init()
        {
            last = null;
        }

        public override void Accumulate(T val)
        {
            if (val != null)
            {
                last = val;
            }
        }

        public override T Terminate()
        {
            return last;
        }

    }
```

Attempt to use:

```
AGG<DataLakeTest.LastNonNull<string>>([b]) OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS bf
```

> Error     E_CSC_USER_UNEXPECTEDOVERCLAUSE: Unexpected OVER clause.
>   Description: An OVER clause must follow a ranking function call (such
>   as RANK() or ROW_NUMBER()) or a WITHIN GROUP clause. Resolution: Make
>   sure the OVER clause immediately follows a ranking function call or a
>   WITHIN GROUP clause.

What kind of user-defined object could I use?

**Update**

Script:

```
@tb1 = SELECT * FROM 
        ( VALUES
        (1, "Val1"),
        (2, (string)null),
          (3, "Val3"),
          (5, (string) null),
          (6, (string)null),
          (7, "Val7"),
          (8, "Val8")
        ) AS T(Timestamp, a);

@tb1 =
    SELECT Timestamp,
           ??? AS a
    FROM @tb1;

OUTPUT @tb1 TO "/test.csv" USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: true);
```

Expected output:

```
"Timestamp","a"
1,"Val1"
2,"Val1"
3,"Val3"
5,"Val3"
6,"Val3"
7,"Val7"
8,"Val8"
```

**Update 2:**

Unfortunately, I can't use LAG function because the count of null values between nonnull values is unknown. And can't use CROSS JOIN because when I have very huge tables then processing step just freezes. My current solution(I'm not happy to use it):

```
@tb1 =
    SELECT Timestamp,
           [a],
           [a] != null && [a] != LEAD([a], 1) OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) AS aSwitch
    FROM @tb1;

@tb1 =
    SELECT Timestamp,
           [a],
           SUM(aSwitch ? 1 : 0) OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS aGrp
    FROM @tb1;

@tb1 =
    SELECT Timestamp,
           FIRST_VALUE([a]) OVER(PARTITION BY aGrp ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) AS a
    FROM @tb1;
```

**Final solution:**

```
public class ReplaceNullReducer : IReducer
{
    string lastValue = null;
    public override IEnumerable<IRow> Reduce(IRowset input, IUpdatableRow output)
    {
        foreach (var row in input.Rows)
        {
            var val = row.Get<string>("a");
            if (val != null) lastValue = val;
            output.Set<string>("a", lastValue);
            output.Set<int>("Timestamp", row.Get<int>("Timestamp"));
            yield return output.AsReadOnly();
        }
    } 
}
```

USQL(for some reason "ALL" option triggers E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR error, so I introduced dumb device column):

```
@tb1 = SELECT * FROM 
        ( VALUES
        (1, "Val1", 1),
        (2, (string)null, 1),
          (3, "Val3", 1),
          (5, (string) null, 1),
          (6, (string)null, 1),
          (7, "Val7", 1),
          (8, "Val8", 1)
        ) AS T(Timestamp, a, device);
@tb1 = REDUCE @tb1 PRESORT [Timestamp] ON device
       PRODUCE [Timestamp] int, [a] string
       USING new DataLakeTest.ReplaceNullReducer();
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Added input data and expected output

Comment: I created a 20 million row test file and the UDO custom reducer scaled really well. My pure U-SQL approach scaled absolutely terribly so I would recommend not using it. I am looking for a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have more than one row with possible NULLs, your solution seems to work, or you could write a custom reducer that operates on the presorted list and returns the value.

E.g.,

```
@raw = SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
        (1, "Val1"),
        (2, (string) null),
        (3, "Val3"),
        (5, (string) null),
        (6, (string) null),
        (7, "Val7"),
        (8, "Val8")
    ) AS T(Timestamp, a);

@res = REDUCE @raw PRESORT Timestamp ALL
       PRODUCE Timestamp int, a string
       USING new ReduceSample.ReplaceNullReducer();
```

Then implement the ReplaceNullReducer as a recursive reducer that steps through the rows to get the a value if it is not null (and sets the null replacement value) until it finds a null value where it then replaces the null with the replacement value. You will have to make sure you cover edge cases such as if the first value is a null value.

The following blog post has more details on a reducer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/06/27/how-do-i-combine-overlapping-ranges-using-u-sql-introducing-u-sql-reducer-udos/

Comment: Hm, I can't compile your sample, if I use ALL then it gives me E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR: syntax error. Expected one of: ASC DESC ON PRODUCE READONLY REQUIRED SORTED USING WITH ')' ','

Comment: Hmmm. Can you leave the ALL away? And send me the statement you wrote or a job link to usql (at) microsoft dot com? According to the documented grammar ALL should be allowed there, but I have not tried it myself yet.

Comment: Just to followup. The position of ALL and ON is currently not well defined. We will clean up the syntax in a future refresh.